# WinInet and SOAP

Tags: windows, winapi, wininet

Currently I use the CURL open transport library to genereate http requests with a soap header. This all is implemented in C/C++. I was able to port this to Windows mobile howver I wonder whether I can use WinInet to do the SOAP request? Just to use less memory on the mobile device.

Are there samples on how to do this?

Thanks in advance
Jasper

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer :)

You could try looking at [gSOAP](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net) which has a gsoapWinInet plugin.